# Reflect Toolbox worked in Scala 2.11 not working in Scala 2.12

Tags: scala, scala-2.12

This code that works in Scala 2.11 doesn't work in 2.12:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
val tb = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
tb.eval(tb.parse("""println("hello!")"""))
```

I get the error below, what changed in 2.12?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   scala.reflect.internal.SymbolPairs$Cursor.matches(Lscala/reflect/internal/Symbols$Symbol;)Z

Note: I had to add to the classpath `scala-compiler-2.12.2.jar`

Comment: which version of reflect library are you using?

Comment: I have in my path also `scala-reflect-2.12.2.jar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible, that you updated your project to Scala 2.12 but left a dependency on `scala-compiler` 2.11 on your classpath ?

Nothing changed in 2.12, with relation to your code. In order for your code to work, you must have a dependency on [scala-compiler](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler).

Here is a SBT project with Scala 2.11, without `scala-compiler` dependency:

```
name := "q53391593"
organization := "sk.ygor.stackoverflow"
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
```

Your code does not compile: `object runtime is not a member of package reflect`, `object tools is not a member of package scala`, `not found: value universe`

You need to add the dependency on `scala-compiler`:

```
name := "q53391593"
organization := "sk.ygor.stackoverflow"
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
scalaVersion := "2.12.6" 
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
```

This will put two additional jars on your classpat: `scala-compiler:2.12.6:jar` and `scala-reflect:2.12.6:jar`. If you are not using SBT, make sure, that you include them by yourself.

Also, note the usage of `scalaVersion.value` to specify the version of the library. This prevents from mixing together incompatible versions of Scala libraries.

Comment: I made a mistake and hardcoded scala version in the `scala-reflect` dependency. Edited answer now.

Answer (score 0):

The scala minor version number in the pom must also be the same as the scala version number in the environment